# Df from long to wide format with multiple id and time variables

Tags: r, merge, long-integer, wide-format-data

I am stuck trying to convert a df from long format to wide format. My data looks like this for one id (example `1102`; in the complete df there are many different ids:

```
>df_long[1:30,]
id      roi             mean       sd     timepoint
1  1102 HarvardOxford1 0.234243 0.1212333    A
2  1102 HarvardOxford2 0.111111 0.1212333    A
3  1102 HarvardOxford3 0.234243 0.1212333    A
4  1102 HarvardOxford4 0.111111 0.4657222    A
5  1102 Lh__F1_head 0.234243 0.1212333        A
6  1102 Lh__F2_body 0.534543 0.4657222        A
7  1102 Lh__F3_tail 0.234243 0.1212333        A
8  1102 Rh__F1_head 0.111111 0.4657222        A
9  1102 Rh__F2body 0.234243 0.1212333         A
10 1102 Rh__F3tail 0.111111 0.4657222         A
11 1102 HarvardOxford1 0.111111 0.1212333    B
12 1102 HarvardOxford2 0.234243 0.4657222    B
13 1102 HarvardOxford3 0.111111 0.4657222    B
14 1102 HarvardOxford4 0.111111 0.1212333    B
15 1102 Lh__F1_head 0.534543 0.4657222        B
16 1102 Lh__F2_body 0.234243 0.4657222        B
17 1102 Lh__F3_tail 0.234243 0.1212333        B
18 1102 Rh__F1_head 0.534543 0.4657222        B
19 1102 Rh__F2body 0.534543 0.4657222         B
20 1102 Rh__F3tail 0.234243 0.1212333         B
21 1102 HarvardOxford1 0.534543 0.4657222    C
22 1102 HarvardOxford2 0.234243 0.4657222    C
23 1102 HarvardOxford3 0.387666 0.4657222    C
24 1102 HarvardOxford4 0.234243 0.4657222    C
25 1102 Lh__F1_head 0.387666 0.4657222        C
26 1102 Lh__F2_body 0.387666 0.4657222        C
27 1102 Lh__F3_tail 0.387666 0.1212333        C
28 1102 Rh__F1_head 0.387666 0.4657222        C
29 1102 Rh__F2body 0.234243 0.1212333         C
30 1102 Rh__F3tail 0.234243 0.1212333         C
```

I want it in the wide format so that for each id there is only one row. So something like:

```
id      roi.A          mean.A  sd.A       roi.A       mean.A.   sd.A ... roi.C 
1 1102 Harvard.Oxford1 0.2342 0.12123 HarvardOxford2 0.1111 0.12123 ... Harvard
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In your example you end up with multiple columns with the same name. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy, however it doesn't make sense to me. May I ask what's the purpose to have a very looong table with similar column names?

```r
Lines <- 
"id roi mean sd timepoint
1102 HarvardOxford1 0.234243 0.1212333 A
1102 HarvardOxford2 0.111111 0.1212333 A
1102 HarvardOxford3 0.234243 0.1212333 A
1102 HarvardOxford4 0.111111 0.4657222 A
1102 Lh__F1_head 0.234243 0.1212333 A
1102 Lh__F2_body 0.534543 0.4657222 A
1102 Lh__F3_tail 0.234243 0.1212333 A
1102 Rh__F1_head 0.111111 0.4657222 A
1102 Rh__F2body 0.234243 0.1212333 A
1102 Rh__F3tail 0.111111 0.4657222 A
1102 HarvardOxford1 0.111111 0.1212333 B
1102 HarvardOxford2 0.234243 0.4657222 B
1102 HarvardOxford3 0.111111 0.4657222 B
"
a<- read.csv(textConnection(Lines), sep=" ", as.is = TRUE, skip = 0)

df <-data.frame()
df<-cbind(id = a[1,1])
for(m in 1:nrow(a)) {
  for (n in 2:4) {
    b<- as.data.frame(a[m,n])
    b<- setNames(b, paste0(names(a[n]),".",a[m,"timepoint"]))
    df<-cbind(df, b)
  }
}

df
#>     id          roi.A   mean.A      sd.A          roi.A   mean.A      sd.A
#> 1 1102 HarvardOxford1 0.234243 0.1212333 HarvardOxford2 0.111111 0.1212333
#>            roi.A   mean.A      sd.A          roi.A   mean.A      sd.A
#> 1 HarvardOxford3 0.234243 0.1212333 HarvardOxford4 0.111111 0.4657222
#>         roi.A   mean.A      sd.A       roi.A   mean.A      sd.A       roi.A
#> 1 Lh__F1_head 0.234243 0.1212333 Lh__F2_body 0.534543 0.4657222 Lh__F3_tail
#>     mean.A      sd.A       roi.A   mean.A      sd.A      roi.A   mean.A
#> 1 0.234243 0.1212333 Rh__F1_head 0.111111 0.4657222 Rh__F2body 0.234243
#>        sd.A      roi.A   mean.A      sd.A          roi.B   mean.B      sd.B
#> 1 0.1212333 Rh__F3tail 0.111111 0.4657222 HarvardOxford1 0.111111 0.1212333
#>            roi.B   mean.B      sd.B          roi.B   mean.B      sd.B
#> 1 HarvardOxford2 0.234243 0.4657222 HarvardOxford3 0.111111 0.4657222
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>